# Can an EU national register for residency in Norway while still working in another EU country?

Tags: residency, norway

I'm wondering whether I can register for residency in Norway while still working in Spain.

I'm a dutch national with a residence permit in Spain (where I'm currently working) and I'm planning to move to Norway, where my partner (Moldovan with a Romanian passport) is living and working already. I'm planning to stay with my Spanish employer for a few more months, while already moving to Norway (with regular visits to Spain). Because my contract is with a Spanish company and I pay taxes there I cannot de-register my Spanish residency yet, but I would already like to start a Norwegian language course with the Voksenopplæring, for which I need either a residence permit or a letter from the police. Should I register in Norway already, despite still being employed in Spain?

thanks for your tips and guidance!

Comment: The question *Can I* is on-topic on this site.  The question *should I* is not, because it is subjective.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no coordinated system of residency registration in the EEA, so de-registering in Spain is not a prerequisite for registering in Norway.  I suppose Spanish or Norwegian law might specify something in this regard, but I doubt it.  Does the Norwegian process include presenting evidence that you've de-registered yourself in your previous place of residence?